# Is there any faster way to select users that bough thing1 and never bough thing2?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. One has users IDs, the second user IDs and what they bough.
I trying to select users ID's (no dupes) that bough `thing1` and never bough `thing2`.

I can use this solution:

```
select distinct usr_id 
  from purchases_tbl 
 where productname = 'thing1' 
   and usr_id not in (select usr_id 
                        from purchases_tbl 
                       where productname = 'thing2');
```

But making two queries is probably not the best solution.

I tried to write this:

```
select acc.usr_id 
  from accounts acc 
       inner join purchases_tbl ptbl 
          on acc.usr_id = ptbl.usr_id 
         and ptbl.productname = 'thing1' 
 where ptbl.productname != 'thing2'
```

but it seems like `where` clause simply has no effect (the result still contains user IDs that bough `thing2`).

Comment: The answer depends on the database engine which you did not specify.

Comment: @DanBracuk - I specified it now. It's MS SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by the users and then take only those having at least one time bought 'thing1' and never 'thing2'

```
select usr_id 
from purchases_tbl 
group by usr_id 
having sum(case when productname = 'thing1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when productname = 'thing2' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use an `except`

```
select user_id
  from purchases_tbl
 where productname = 'thing1'
except
select user_id
  from purchases_tbl
 where productname = 'thing2'
```

This may (or may not) be as efficient as the `group by` `having` approach but it tends to be a bit more self-documenting about exactly what logic you want to implement.